# Flutter: Error "The getter 'mydata' isn't defined for the type 'providerdemo' " eventhough I've defined them in providerdemo classs

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I've defined a variable myvalue for accessing the document field from cloud firestore in Provider class providerdemo .But when I am trying to access it shows **error** `The getter 'mydata' isn't defined for the type 'providerdemo'.` .What's wrong in my code ?

**providerdemo.dart**

```
class providerdemo with ChangeNotifier {
  static String? mydata;
  final userData = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("Users")
      .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
      .get()
      .then((value) {
     mydata =(value.data()?['uname'] ?? "Default userName");
}
```

Below is the class where I'm trying to access the value into `Text()` widget;

```
class _testState extends State<test> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
     body: Text(Provider.of<providerdemo>(context).mydata ?? "default"),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error `The getter 'mydata' isn't defined for the type 'providerdemo'` because you have not defined the function `mydata` in the `providerdemo` class

---

Further there are two problems:

1. You are defining the `mydata` twice, because of which it is not updating ,
2. It is not `value.data() ?? ["uname"]` it is `value.data()["uname"] ?? "Default userName"`

```
class providerdemo with ChangeNotifier {
  static String mydata;
  final userData = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("Users")
      .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
      .get()
      .then((value) {

    // var mydata = (value.data() ?? ["uname"]); //  You are creating new variable mydata
      
       mydata = (value.data()?['uname'] ?? "Default userName"); // Replace the above line by this

       print(mydata)  // Print the data once so that you know if the correct data is fetched.
  });
  notifyListeners();
}
```

So now you can use it as `Text(providerdemo.mydata)`

---

#### Edit

##### Create Notifier

```
class UsersState extends ChangeNotifier{
String userName = '';

void getName(){
  FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("Users")
      .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
      .get()
      .then((value) {
         userName = (value.data()?[' uname'] ?? "Default userName");
         print(userName)  // Print the data once so that you know if the correct data is fetched.
    });
    notifyListeners();
}
```

##### Change your main.dart file to contain `Notifier`

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<UserState>(
      create: (context)=> UsersState(),
      child:MaterialApp(
        home: myHomePage(),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

##### Screen where you want to display the name

```
class ProfileScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const ProfileScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Provider.of<UserState>(context, listen: false).getName();
    final String name = Provider.of<UsersState>(context).userName;

    return Center(
      child: Text(name),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: But I'm getting following errors: The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null',The instance member 'mydata' can't be accessed in an initializer

Comment: ok,but the error The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'. is still showing and it says  The static getter 'mydata' can't be accessed through an instance

Comment: I have modified my code above .I am getting error :The static getter 'mydata' can't be accessed through an instance.

Comment: Please join with me in the chat [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250767/discussion-between-krishna-acharya-and-devika).

Comment: I have updated the entire code with steps to be done in the provider. let me know if it works !

Answer (score 2):

You didn't declare the variable in the class scope, only in the function scope. So what you have to do, is declare the variable like this:

```dart
class providerdemo with ChangeNotifier {
    final mydata;

    void setMydata(final data) {
        mydata = data;
        notifyListeners();
    }
}
```

And for the best logic separation, you should create another file with for example a Cloud class, where you will write all the firebase related functions. Then when you initialise your app, you should call the following function like this: `final data = Cloud.getMydata();`, and use the setMydata function from your provider file in your UI code to update the variable.

```dart
class Cloud {
    static dynamic getMydata() async {
        return await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("Users")
            .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
            .get();
    }
}
```

(Didn't test the code)
Also, please use CamelCase for class names.

Comment: my error got cleared but the provider is not showing the data on Text widget instead getting the string ```default``` which I provided for null safety .```Text(Provider.of<providerdemo>(context).mydata ?? "default")```

Comment: Also final variable can be initialized only once so your code gives error